# Deprojection of distances in galaxies

Tags: galaxy, astronomy

I have the data (RA and Dec values) for all the knots in a galaxy that is inclined, with the angle of inclination being 41 degrees. How can I estimate the deprojected distance? I found one paper van der Marel and Cioni (2001) (https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/323099/fulltext/201194.text.html). Are there any other papers I can refer to?